# How to install BCM43412 driver on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, wifi, drivers, broadcom

I have installed Fedora and I have problems trying to install the Broadcom BCM43412 Driver for wireless connections.

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer if you tell us what you've tried so far, why it failed, or where are you getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to enable `rpmfusion` repo on your system ( free + non free repo) , it depends on your fedora version following the steps descried [here](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/)

To get the wifi working , you need to install the `broadcom-wl` package , then enable the `wl` module. Also you should **disable the secure boot** from your bios settings because the `wl` module isn't signed.

To install the driver run the following command:

```
yum install broadcom-wl
modprobe wl
```

Comment: It returns modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64

Comment: @LuisVeliz install the `kernel-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Check kernel-devel matches the current kernel

```
dnf install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

Then rebuild kernel modules

```
akmods --force
```

Enable wireless module

```
modprobe wl
```